# Taking multiple lines from a file and creating hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm taking a file and reading in it's contents and creating a hash based on newlines. I've been able to make a hash based on the contents of each line, but how can I create a hash based on the content of everything before the next blank newline? Below is what I have so far.

Input:

```
Title   49th parallel
URL     http://artsweb.bham.ac.uk/
Domain  artsweb.bham.ac.uk

Title   ABAA booknet
URL     http://abaa.org/
Domain  abaa.org
```

Code:

```
File.readlines('A.cfg').each do |line|
  unless line.strip.empty?
    hash = Hash[*line.strip.split("\t")]
    puts hash
  end
  puts "\n" if line.strip.empty?
end
```

Outputs:

```
{"Title"=>"49th parallel"}
{"URL"=>"http://artsweb.bham.ac.uk/"}
{"Domain"=>"artsweb.bham.ac.uk"}

{"Title"=>"ABAA booknet"}
{"URL"=>"http://abaa.org/"}
{"Domain"=>"abaa.org"}
```

Desired Output:

```
{"Title"=>"49th parallel", "URL"=>"http://artsweb.bham.ac.uk/", "Domain"=>"artsweb.bham.ac.uk"}

{"Title"=>"ABAA booknet", "URL"=>"http://abaa.org/", "Domain"=>"abaa.org"}
```

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You have spaces delimiting `"Domain"` and it value, whereas in your code you are delimiting with `"\t"`. So you should not be able to get the output you claim you do.

Comment: @sawa I think it's clear that the input file is actually tab-delimited and that it simply didn't survive copy-and-pasting.  Switching back to tabs, I get the exact output claimed.

Comment: @sawa Given the output, it's extremely clear.  You seem to be presuming the OP is lying.

Comment: @DarshanComputing I am not presuming that the OP is lying about the output. I am actually presuming that the OP is "lying" about what he/she says he/she has as the input.

Comment: Sadly the data is quite messy. The above snippet is spaces, where other pieces of the data are tab delimited.

Comment: @bswinnerton Well, for robustness of your code, it is usually better to use things like `\s+` or `[ \t]+` rather than specifying a particular white character in your regex.

Comment: +1 @sawa. Or, to normalize the data before attempting to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your existing code, this does what you want:

```
hash = {}
File.readlines('A.cfg').each do |line|
  if line.strip.empty?
    puts hash if not hash.empty?
    hash = {}
    puts "\n"
  else
    hash.merge!(Hash[*line.strip.split("\t")])
  end
end

puts hash
```

You can likely simplify that depending on what you're actually doing with the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
open('A.cfg', &:read)
.strip.split(/#$/{2,}/)
.map{|s| Hash[s.scan(/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)/)]}
```

gives

```
[
  {
    "Title"  => "49th",
    "URL"    => "http://artsweb.bham.ac.uk/",
    "Domain" => "artsweb.bham.ac.uk"
  },
  {
    "Title"  => "ABAA",
    "URL"    => "http://abaa.org/",
    "Domain" => "abaa.org"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

read the whole content of the file using read:

```
contents = ""
File.open('A.cfg').do |file|
  contents = file.read
end
```

And then split the contents on two newline characters:

```
contents.split("\n\n")
```

And lastly, create a function pretty similar to what you already have to parse those chunks.

Please note that if you are working on windows it may happen that you need to split on a different sequence because of the carriage return character.

Comment: If you have concerns about compatibility, use `$/`, not `"\n"`.

Comment: @sawa I have never seen this. Can you point me to somewhere I can read about its usage?

Comment: @sawa thank you for the link. I did not realize you are reffering to a predefined vairable, I thought this is some regex magic I somehow missed.

Comment: Maybe the way I wrote was not clear enough, it may have looked like the anchor. Sorry.